# Mysql database connection without port listening?

Tags: mysql, port

can I connect mysql database without port listening ( like 3306 ) using any of the programming language?

is it possible?

if your answer is yes please explain detailed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have knowledge about the things you are asking?

Comment: yes I have some knowledge about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql supports several protocols

```
Protocol Connection Protocol                             Permissible Operating Systems
TCP      TCP/IP connection to local or remote server     All
SOCKET   Unix socket file connection to local server     Unix only
PIPE     Named-pipe connection to local or remote server Windows only
MEMORY   Shared-memory connection to local server        Windows only
```

A port is used only for TCP protocol.

Further reading

- [Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html#option_general_protocol)
- [MySql Connectors and APIs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-connectors.html)